# css box doesn't fit in correctly

Tags: css, margin

I do have this piece of html and css code,and I want my table(id = "table") to fit in higher in the "box".But there is a little margin over a header that says "Kalkulatory macierzowe".So how can I fix it?
HTML

```
<div id = "box">    
<div class = "table" id = "table">
<div id = "header">Kalkulatory macierzowe</div>

<div id = "table1">
<div class = "header">Wyznacznik [2x2]</div>
    <form id = "row1">
        <input type = "text" class = "det1"/><!--first row-->
        <input type = "text" class = "det1"/>
    </form>
    <form id = "row2">
        <input type = "text" class = "det1"/><!--second row-->
        <input type = "text" class = "det1"/>
    </form>
    <div class = "count"><a href = "#"  onclick="det('det1','caclValue2')">Wylicz</a></div>
        <input type = "text" id = "calcValue2"/>
    </div>

<div id = "table2">
<div class = "header">Wyznacznik [3x3]</div>
 <form id = "row1"><!--first row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
 </form>
 <form id = "row2"><!--second row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
</form>
<form id = "row3"><!--third row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
</form>
<div class = "count" onclick="det(3,'det')"><a href = "#">Wylicz</a></div>
<input type = "text" id = "calcValue1"/>
</div>

<div id = "table3">
<div class = "header">Macierz odwrotna [2x2]</div>
 <form id = "row1">
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/><!--first row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/>
 </form>
 <form id = "row2">
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/><!--second row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det2"/>
</form>
<div class = "count" onclick="invertedMatrix(2,'det2')"><a href = "#">Wylicz</a>    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box{
border-collapse:collapse;
width:1070px;
min-width: 1045px;
height: 600px;
min-height: 600px;
margin:auto;
background-color:rgb(25,88,179);
background:url('images/box.jpg');
box-shadow:0px 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #FFFFFF;
}

table{
position:relative;
top:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border-right:2px inset rgb(0,0,0);
border-left:2px inset rgb(0,0,0);
border-top:2px inset rgb(150,150,150);
border-bottom:none;
width:1067px;
min-width:1067px;
height: 599px;
min-height: 599px;

}
#header{
margin-top:0;
height:30px;
max-height:30px;
text-align:left;
font-size:16px;
font-family:Georgia, serif;
background-color:rgb(32,74,109);
color:rgb(255,255,255);
border-bottom:2px inset rgb(0,0,0);
clear:left;
}
```

Comment: I want a margin above #header to be removed

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the `<body>` default margin you're talking about? I don't see any other margin above `#header`.. http://jsfiddle.net/sUUBP/

Comment: You don't have any `<table>` here in HTML, why did you put the `table{}` tag in CSS?

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sUUBP/4/)  Edited the code,cause I haven't given enought to see what margin I was talking about.Now you can see it.Please help with it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need this:

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

Comment: This is something so simple, yet so frustrating. I have been searching for getting the div boxes and footers to be seamless with the sides of the window. While the whole problem is with the body default margin. I have had this problem before, fixed it. Finally found this post and fixed it again. This really needs more votes.